# render rmarkdown file in command line got Error: path for html_dependency not provided

Tags: html, r-markdown

I'm trying to render a Rmarkdown file in linux and eventually I want it to generate a dynamic .html file for people to checkout. The command I'm using is

```
R -e "rmarkdown::render('./test_rshiny2.Rmd',output_file='./results/Diagnos_Plot.html')".
```

However I kept getting this error:

```
Error: path for html_dependency not provided.
```

Below is my the session info:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /opt/htcf/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/r-3.6.3-wjv45rejzld4tqrpekyen7mtmm2ko6qo/rlib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /opt/htcf/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu16.04-x86_64/gcc-5.4.0/r-3.6.3-wjv45rejzld4tqrpekyen7mtmm2ko6qo/rlib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3
```

Can anyone here provide some help?
Thanks so much!!

Comment: Any luck on figuring this out?